# only execute function with ng-click if input fields are not empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I only want to perform this function if the other two fields are not empty, not sure how to do it.

```
ng-click="saveToList($event)"
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-xs-5">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a Title/Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="urlName" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvName" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a URL</label>
                <input type="text" id="urlLink" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvUrl" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
              <a href="javascript:" ng-click="saveToList($event)" class="btn btn-block post">Post</a>
          </div>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.saveToList = function(event) {

    var mvName = $scope.mvName.trim();
    var mvUrl = $scope.mvUrl.trim();

    if (mvName.length > 0) {
      $scope.favUrls.$add({
        name: mvName,
        title: mvUrl
      });
        urlName.value = ''; //urlName is the ID of  input box - Angular rocks!
      urlLink.value = ''; //urlName is the ID of  input box - Angular rocks!
    }

}
```

I get this error when they are empty:

```
Error: $scope.mvName is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't anything to do with Angular: `.trim()` doesn't work against undefined values.  Check to see if the variable is defined before trying to trim it, for example:

```
var mvName = ($scope.mvName) ? $scope.mvName.trim() : '' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `$scope.mvName` in your controller! As it is empty, you are getting an error at line `var mvName = $scope.mvName.trim();`

**EDIT**

```
<a href="javascript:" ng-click="(!mvName && !mvUrl) ? saveToList($event) : ''" class="btn btn-block post">Post</a>
```

Comment: whoever given downvote probably don't know any angularJS OR didn't understand the question! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add ng-disabled directive to your a tag. Something like this:

```
<a href ng-disabled="!mvName || !mvUrl" ng-click="saveToList($event)" class="btn btn-block post">Post</a>
```

or check that vars in your js:

```
$scope.saveToList = function(event) {
   if(!$scope.mvName || !$scope.mvUrl)
      return;

    var mvName = $scope.mvName.trim();
    var mvUrl = $scope.mvUrl.trim();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a Title/Description</label>
    <input type="text" id="urlName" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvName" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="urlLink" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvUrl" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <a href="javascript:" 
    ng-click="(mvName != '' && mvUrl != '') && saveToList($event)" class="btn btn-block post">Post</a>
</div>
```

Or use `ng-disabled="mvName === '' && mvUrl === ''"`

Other options would be to not render the button: `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

Comment: Why not to do `ng-click="mvName && mvUrl && saveToList($event)"` instead of `ng-click="(mvName != '' && mvUrl != '') && saveToList($event)"`?

Comment: Also possible I suppose. I prefer more explicit code/checks in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

How about performing a simple check to see if the fields are empty or not, before you perform any comparisons using the value. That should solve the issue I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="myForm">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a Title/Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="urlName" required class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvName" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a URL</label>
        <input type="text" id="urlLink" required class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvUrl" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a href="javascript:" ng-enabled="myForm.$valid" ng-click="saveToList($event)" class="btn btn-block post">Post</a>
      </div>    
    </form>
```

Try using the angular validation.